# php function & symbol

Tags: php, function, ampersand

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does it mean to start a PHP function with an ampersand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676897/what-does-it-mean-to-start-a-php-function-with-an-ampersand)

hi

Why is it that some php functions have a '&' in their signature for example

```
function &getData()
```

Answer (score 6):

[It returns a reference to a variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php).