# PHP and ampersand

Tags: php, ampersand

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does it mean to start a PHP function with an ampersand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676897/what-does-it-mean-to-start-a-php-function-with-an-ampersand)

I would like to share what I think to know and what I don't understand about the ampersand in PHP language (version < 5.3).

I think I know the basic usage, e.g.:

```
$var = 'foo';
echo $var; //output foo
$var2 = &$var;
$var2 = 'bar';
echo $var2; //output bar
```

So far, so good. Let's try with objects:

```
class Person {public $name='john';}
$person = new Person();
echo $person->name;//outputs john
$person2 = &$person;
$person2->name = 'doe';
echo $person->name;//obviously outputs doe
```

Note that the above code leads to the same result without the ampersand, given both `$person` and `$person2 (= $person)` refer to the same object (as in Java), so any change on the object will be retrieved by both variables.

So far, I can say the ampersand operator is only useful for primitives. However, there is something I just don't understand.

Although, I understand this usage:

```
function superplusplus(&$base) {$base++;}
$var = 2;
superplusplus($var);
echo $var;//outputs 3
```

What I don't get is this is the usage of ampersand like below:

```
function &superplusplus($var) {$var++;}
```

It doesn't seem to have any effect, as if there was no ampersand at all.

What is this syntax supposed to do?

Comment: it is very rare that you would ever actually want to use an amp in PHP. objects and resources are passed by reference automatically.

Comment: Objects are indeed passed by reference... since PHP5.  In PHP4, this wasn't the case.  That's why you'll see a lot of this in PHP4 code, and very little of it in PHP5.

Comment: *(related)* [What does that symbol mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)