# Use of & keyword in PHP

Tags: php, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

What is the use of the `&` keyword in PHP?

Comment: Take a look [this] (http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)

Answer (score 0):

Passing by reference.Check this link

http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php

Answer (score 0):

An ampersand preceding a variable means it is a reference to a variable instead of a copy of a value.

Comment: What if it's preceding a function?

Comment: The function will return a reference to a variable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676897/what-does-it-mean-to-start-a-php-function-with-an-ampersand