# Is there a valid technical use for returning by reference in PHP5

Tags: php, oop, php-5.3

My question is a follow up to the following question: [What does it mean to start a php function with an ampersand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676897/what-does-it-mean-to-start-a-php-function-with-an-ampersand)

The example code used in the question is this:

```
class FacebookRestClient {
...
    public function &users_hasAppPermission($ext_perm, $uid=null) {
        return $this->call_method('facebook.users.hasAppPermission', 
        array('ext_perm' => $ext_perm, 'uid' => $uid));
    }
...
}
```

Why would a reference be necessary when we already have a reference ($this)?

The [chosen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676911/671191) quotes the following from the [PHP manual on Returning References](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php)

> Returning by reference is useful when you want to use a function to find to which variable a reference should be bound. Do not use return-by-reference to increase performance. The engine will automatically optimize this on its own. Only return references when you have a valid technical reason to do so.

The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676963/671191) gives a reason why this technique was needed in PHP4. But I don't find the answer for why it is needed in PHP5 very convincing.

Does anybody know of any valid reason(s) for using this technique in PHP5?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, here's an example from my codebase.

I have a "factory" class for each model, such as UserFactory. When I call UserFactory::findOne() I return a reference to the model, which is stored in an array in UserFactory.

I do this so that if I get the user model and modify something in it, and then get it again later in my code, it is updated with the new information even though I never went back to the database.

For example:

```
<?php
$user = UserModel::findOne([ '_id' => 151 ]);
$user->status = 'disabled';

// Much later
$user = UserModel::findOne([ '_id' => 151 ]);
if ( $user->status != 'disabled' ) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Returning by reference is a good way of accomplishing this without making two calls to my database.

Comment: Doesn't it get returned by reference anyway? I'm missing something

Comment: You can't return a value by reference unless you explicitly use the & in the function definition. You could in PHP4 but not in PHP5